# Как расставить поля формы в определённом порядке с определённым условием?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Попробую понятно объяснить свой вопрос

Есть форма с полями:

```
<input name="city[]" value="Киев"><input name="time[]" value="12:00">
<input name="city[]" value="Москва"><input name="time[]" value="16:00">
<input name="city[]" value="Минск"><input name="time[]" value="22:00">
```

И есть JSON (он приходит в таком виде без времени и ни как по другому )

```
{"address_list":[{"city":"Минск"},{"city":"Киев"},{"city":"Москва"}]}
```

И вот сама задача. Нужно перестроить форму в том порядке, как указанно в JSON. И самое главное что если "Минск" переместился в верх, то и время которое было указанно у него тоже должно переместиться верх.

Пожалуйста, подскажите кто чем может!

Comment: Возможно проще генерировать исходя из полученного объекта? Иначе нужно сгруппировать инпуты по парам

Comment: @RuslanSemenov Я думал в сторону формирования новой формы исходя из JSON, но не могу придумать как правильно присвоить своему городу

Comment: Вы отправляете массивы `city[]` и `time[]` вы можете привязать массивы к друг-другу, будет значить в другом ключ события. Исходя из этого - мы можем сортировать в нужном нам порядке.

Comment: передавать нужно: город и время, тогда обычный цикл, который выведет форму в нужном порядке

Answer (score 2):

Вот мой вариант:

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');
const address_list = [{
    city: 'Минск',
    time: '16:00'
  },
  {
    city: 'Киев',
    time: '14:00'
  },
  {
    city: 'Москва',
    time: '17:00'
  }
];


for (i = 0; i < address_list.length; i++) {
  let el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerHTML = `<input name="city[]" value="${address_list[i].city}"><input name="time[]" value="${address_list[i].time}">`;
  result.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');
const address_list = [{
    city: 'Минск'
  },
  {
    city: 'Киев'
  },
  {
    city: 'Москва'
  }
];

for (i = 0; i < address_list.length; i++) {
  let el = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="' + address_list[i].city + '"]'); // выбор по содержанию
  let parent = el[0].parentNode;
  //let el = document.getElementById(address_list[i].city);
  result.appendChild(parent);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="city[]" value="Киев">
  <input name="time[]" value="12:00">
</div>
<div>
  <input name="city[]" value="Москва">
  <input name="time[]" value="16:00">
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <input name="city[]" value="Минск">
  <input name="time[]" value="22:00">
</div>

<hr>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Моя ошибка была в описании. JSON приходит без времени, только город!

Comment: добавил, второй вариант

Answer (score 0):

```js
const jsonString = '{"address_list":[{"city":"Минск"},{"city":"Киев"},{"city":"Москва"}]}';
const addressList = JSON.parse(jsonString).address_list;

const form = document.querySelector('.form');

const switchTime = (item) => {
  switch(item.city){
    case 'Минск':
      return '22:00';
    case 'Киев':
      return '12:00'
    case 'Москва':
      return '16:00'
  }
}

let formHtml = '';

addressList.forEach((item) => {
  formHtml += `<input name="city[]" value="${item.city}">
               <input name="time[]" value="${switchTime(item)}">`;
})

form.innerHTML = formHtml;
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input name="city[]" value="Киев"><input name="time[]" value="12:00">
  <input name="city[]" value="Москва"><input name="time[]" value="16:00">
  <input name="city[]" value="Минск"><input name="time[]" value="22:00">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json = {"address_list": [{"city": "Минск"}, {"city": "Киев"}, {"city": "Москва"}]};
var list = json.address_list;

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  $("[name='city[]'][value='" + list[i].city + "']").next().addBack().appendTo("form");
}
```

```css
input {
 float: left;
}

input[name='time[]'] {
 float: none;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
 <input name="city[]" value="Киев"><input name="time[]" value="12:00">
 <input name="city[]" value="Москва"><input name="time[]" value="16:00">
 <input name="city[]" value="Минск"><input name="time[]" value="22:00">
</form>
```